# How to use aes_encrypt in C# Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

I have been mainly writing in PHP and only know one way to create an aes encryption for a variable:

`aes_encrypt(variableName, 'SecretSalt')`

I need to encrypt a variable in C# and I have tried a similar approach as in PHP but it is not working (I get an error "The name aes does not exist in current context"

Here is my current code in C#:

```
        var username = txtusername.Text;
        var password = txtpassword.Text;
        var usernameAES = aes_encrypt(username, 'mySalt');
```

What is the correct way to use `AES_ENCRYPT`? I am sending the variable to a PHP Web Service

Update:
More C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

        private void Login()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtusername.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert username");
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtpassword.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please insert password");
        }
        var Token = "TMMZC 77385 R8G2D6";
        var username = txtusername.Text;
        var password = txtpassword.Text;
        var usernameAES = aes_encrypt(username, 'mySalt');
        var url = "https://mydomain.co.za/LoginVerification.php?";
        var var = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&Token=" + Token Token;
        var URL = url + var;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.  
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.  
        var responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        //MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
        // Display the content.  
        if (responseFromServer == "Allow")
        {
            //Open Form1
            Form1 Form = new Form1();
            Form.Show();

            //CLose Password Form
            Password PasswordForm = new Password();
            PasswordForm.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What library or class are you using that gives you `aes_encrypt` ?  The error message you are getting is usually created by a HttpContext pipeline. So whatever that is doing it is breaking there due to something. Maybe you can find a NuGet package that does the encryption you need instead? https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Tags%3A%22aes%22 - I used `RijndaelCryptography` for some specific encryption stuff it is pretty good.

Comment: There is no PHP standard function called `aes_encrypt`, so you'd first have to identify the actual algorithm it uses by hunting it down. MySQL has an `aes_encrypt`, you might be thinking of that one. In general, you're going to have a very hard time with an approach for translating your existing knowledge that boils down to "let's just take a function name and put it in my C# code to see if it will compile", because it never will. The .NET standard library is organized in [classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes), not functions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert. I never said that `aes_encrypt` is a "PHP standard function". I said I "only know one way to create an aes encryption for a variable". I am aware that it is a MySQL function.

Comment: @ppumkin. Thank you

Comment: I *wasn't* familiar until I looked it up, since I'm not a PHP programmer... context helps, since there's a lot of ways a function called `aes_encrypt` that takes a salt could go about things. It particularly matters whether or not you need that exact algorithm (to interoperate with existing code), or just something that works roughly like it (and all the rest of the code is C# too, or is at least the code that will ultimately decrypt is).

Comment: @JeroenMostert. I am sending the variables to a PHP Web Service on my server. The Web Service script is protected by HTTPS. The reason I want to encrypt the data is because I want to prevent it from being interrupted and seen by unwanted eyes. Is it necessary to encrypt or am I just paranoid. The data will be encrypted and inserted to my database by the Web-Service after username and password was verified.

Comment: Data sent over HTTPS need not be encrypted just to keep it secret over the wire, since HTTPS already encrypts it and guards against that. There's still the matter of what happens with the data after it's received. If the PHP service logs the data in a plaintext file that's not protected, or the data is inserted into a database without encryption, then encrypting it yourself is not superfluous. But if the data in question is or includes a password, then arguably even encrypting it is wrong -- it should be *hashed*, not encrypted, and only the hash should ever be stored and compared.

Comment: @JeroenMostert. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;


public string EncryptText(string input, string password)
{
    // Get the bytes of the string
    byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

    // Hash the password with SHA256
    passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

    byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);

    string result = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesEncrypted);

    return result;
}

public byte[] aes_encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

    // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
    // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return encryptedBytes;
}
```